# KDevelop and custom syntax coloring

Tags: kde, syntax-highlighting, kdevelop

I am currently trying out KDevelop 5.2.1 for a C++ project on Ubuntu 18 and so far, everything is working as expected, except syntax coloring. I have not been able to personalize it the way I want. What I am doing is the following:

1. Settings -> Configure KDevelop... -> Editor -> Fonts & Colors
2. New Schema
3. There I change the colors, default text styles and Highlight text style (for C++)

When I change colors there, some have the wanted effect (ex.: backgroung) but others seem to have no effect (ex.: macros). For example, for a custom macro function, I have not been able so far to change from the blue/greeninsh default coloring. Same for custom types or variables (which seem to be randomly colored).

In Highlighting Text Style, I have tried setting everything to white and to my surprise, most of the code is still colored (I was looking at a `.cpp` file).

Is there something I am doing wrong? How can I change these colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor settings are inherited from KTextEditor, and apply when KDevelop's semantic highlighting doesn't override them, e.g. for files not in a supported language.

The hues used for semantic highlighting [aren't configurable currently](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395856).

They're blended with the underlying editor colour; the intensity is configurable under "Configure KDevelop -> Language Support", including disabling it by setting this to zero.